# How to find an Index of a string in a list

Tags: c#, string, list, indexing

So what I am trying do is retrieve the index of the first item, in the list, that begins with "whatever", I am not sure how to do this.

My attempt (lol):

```
List<string> txtLines = new List<string>();
//Fill a List<string> with the lines from the txt file.
foreach(string str in File.ReadAllLines(fileName)) {
  txtLines.Add(str);
}
//Insert the line you want to add last under the tag 'item1'.
int index = 1;
index = txtLines.IndexOf(npcID);
```

Yea I know it isn't really anything, and it is wrong because it seems to be looking for an item that is equal to npcID rather than the line that begins with it.

Comment: it does actually display index of string. Check out http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?  If `txtLines` is a textbox, just do `txtLines.Text.IndexOf(ncpID)`.

Comment: Sorry just fixed it up, for some reason the code didn't paste. Oh well fixed

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want "StartsWith" you can use `FindIndex`

```
 int index = txtLines.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("whatever"));
```

Answer (score 2):

if your txtLines is a List Type, you need to put it in a loop, after that retrieve the value

```
int index = 1;
foreach(string line in txtLines) {
     if(line.StartsWith(npcID)) { break; }
     index ++;
}
```

Comment: You might want to exit the loop at some point when you find the string.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose txtLines was filled, now :

```
List<int> index = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < txtLines.Count(); i++)
{
    index.Add(i);
}
```

now you have a list of int contain index of all txtLines elements. you can call first element of `List<int> index` by this code : `index.First();`